# Error with confusion matrix: Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix, rpart

Edited Question:

I have a data set of 699 rows and in the exercise I'm working on it is requested to generate a training set of 300 observations. The rest will be the test set. I write all the possible information in order to make the situation clearer as possible.

```
#First part of the code & Preprocessing
attach(Cancer_data)
names(Cancer_data)[1] <- "id"
names(Cancer_data)[2] <- "thickness"
names(Cancer_data)[3] <- "unif.size"
names(Cancer_data)[4] <- "unif.shape"
names(Cancer_data)[5] <- "adhesion"
names(Cancer_data)[6] <- "size"
names(Cancer_data)[7] <- "nuclei"
names(Cancer_data)[8] <- "chromatin"
names(Cancer_data)[9] <- "nucleoli"
names(Cancer_data)[10] <- "mitoses" 
names(Cancer_data)[11] <- "Prognosis"   
#Prognosis are my class labels 2 for benign cancer 4 for malignant
Prognosis <- as.factor(Cancer_data$Prognosis)
Cancer_data <- Cancer_data %>% dplyr :: select(-id)
```

Passing directly to the rpart model, avoiding to re-write data splitting that is clear enough, I implement this classification tree model with r part

```
rpart_model <- rpart(Prognosis ~.,method = "class",data = train_set)
#The train_set was implemented before with caret:: createDataPrtition()
```

Now it is the main issue because when I predict the tree performances on the test_set and I try to obtain the confusionMatrix R returns me this error:

```
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

here the implemented code

```
y_hat <- predict(rpart_model,test_set)
confusionMatrix(Cancer_data$Prognosis,y_hat)
```

I tried also

```
y_hat <- predict(rpart_model,type ='class')
```

as it was suggested in a previous  [Post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163747/rpart-classification-why-is-my-predict-output-not-adhering-to-type-class)

I apologize for the length of the question but I preferred to be as more precise as I could. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Help others help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, we don't have access to or know anything about the structure of `Cancer_data`, so it's hard to see what the disconnect between `test_set$Prognosis` and `pred_tree_test` ends up being. One thing perhaps to look at is the discrepancy between `levels(test_set$Prognosis)` and `levels(pred_tree_test)`

Comment: Let me put it this way: The most likely problem seems to be that the predictions do not contain all the levels of `Prognosis`, but it is literally impossible to tell without seeing either the data or the output of the two commands I mention in my last comment.